# HighCharts Custom Back Button while using SetChart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I want to add custom back button as it is having multiple drill down with multiple drill series,

I almost achieved but i cant able to take the current series categories, if i took the current series categories i can able to achieve the custom back button

And also the script is growing more and more, so is there any idea for custom back button for this code

```
$(function () {

              (function (H) {
                    //For X-axis labels
                    H.wrap(H.Point.prototype, 'init', function (proceed, series, options, x) {
                        var point = proceed.call(this, series, options, x),
                            chart = series.chart,
                            tick = series.xAxis && series.xAxis.ticks[x],
                            tickLabel = tick && tick.label;
                        //console.log("series");
                        //console.log(series);
                        console.log("Point = ");
                        console.log(point);

                        if (point.drilldown) {

                            if (tickLabel) {
                                if (!tickLabel._basicStyle) {
                                    tickLabel._basicStyle = tickLabel.element.getAttribute('style');
                                }
                                tickLabel.addClass('highcharts-drilldown-axis-label').css({
                                    'text-decoration': 'underline',
                                    'font-weight': 'normal',
                                    'cursor': 'pointer',
                                    'color':'brown'
                                    }).on('click', function (){
                                    //alert('clicked');
                                    //point.doDrilldown(); 
                                    point.firePointEvent('click')  
                                    });
                            }
                        } 
                        else if (tickLabel && tickLabel._basicStyle) 
                        {
                        }

                        return point;
                    });
                })(Highcharts);

                    var chart;
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        categories1 = ['Jan', 'Feb'],
                        name1 = 'Planned Leaves',

                        data1 = [
            {
                 name:'Jan',
                 y: 50,
                 colorByPoint: true,
                 drilldown: {
                     name: 'Jan Planned Leaves',
                     categories: ['Admin', 'HR', 'IT', 'Site Row'],
                     data: [
                     {
                        y:30,
                        colorByPoint: true,
                        drilldown :
                            {
                                name:'Admin Planned Leaves',
                                categories:['Keerthi','Vinith','Rahul'],
                                data:[5,6,8]
                            }

                     }, 
                     {
                        y:40,
                        colorByPoint: true,
                        drilldown :
                            {
                                name:'HR Planned Leaves',
                                categories:['Keerthi','Vinith','Rahul'],
                                data:[5,6,8]
                            }

                     }

                     ],

                 }
             },
             {
                 name:'Feb',
                 y: 50,
                 colorByPoint: true,
                 drilldown: {
                     name: 'Feb Planned Leaves',
                     categories: ['Admin', 'HR', 'IT', 'Site Row'],
                     data: [
                     {

                        y:30,
                        colorByPoint: true,
                        drilldown :
                            {
                                name:'Admin Planned Leaves',
                                categories:['Keerthi','Vinith','Rahul'],
                                data:[5,6,8]
                            }

                     }, 
                     {

                        y:40,
                        colorByPoint: true,
                        drilldown :
                            {
                                name:'HR Planned Leaves',
                                categories:['Keerthi','Vinith','Rahul'],
                                data:[5,6,8]
                            }

                     }
                     ],

                 }
             },

            ];        





                var colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors,
                        categories2 = ['Jan', 'Feb'],
                        name2 = 'Unplanned Leaves',
                        data2 = [  
            {
                 name:'Jan',
                 y: 55,
                 colorByPoint: true,
                   drilldown: {
                     name: 'Jan Unplanned Leaves',
                     categories: ['Admin', 'HR', 'IT', 'Site Row'],
                     data: [
                     {

                        y:30,
                        colorByPoint: true,
                        drilldown :
                            {
                                name:'Admin Unplanned Leaves',
                                categories:['Keerthi','Vinith','Rahul'],
                                data:[5,6,8]
                            }

                     }, 
                     {

                        y:40,
                        colorByPoint: true,
                        drilldown :
                            {
                                name:'HR Unplanned Leaves',
                                categories:['Keerthi','Vinith','Rahul'],
                                data:[5,6,8]
                            }

                     } 

                     ],

                 },
             },
             {
                 name:'Feb',
                 y: 55,
                 colorByPoint: true,
                   drilldown: {
                     name: 'Feb Unplanned Leaves',
                     categories: ['Admin', 'HR', 'IT', 'Site Row'],
                     data: [
                     {

                        y:30,
                        colorByPoint: true,
                        drilldown :
                            {
                                name:'Admin Unplanned Leaves',
                                categories:['Keerthi','Vinith','Rahul'],
                                data:[5,6,8]
                            }

                     }, 
                     {

                        y:40,
                        colorByPoint: true,
                        drilldown :
                            {
                                name:'HR Unplanned Leaves',
                                categories:['Keerthi','Vinith','Rahul'],
                                data:[5,6,8]
                            }

                     }

                     ],

                 },
             },
            ];     
                       categories3 = ['Jan', 'Feb','mar'],
                        name3 = 'pnun',
                        data3 = [  
            {
                 name:'Jan',
                   drilldown: {
                      name: 'Jan planned Leaves',
                     categories: ['Admin', 'HR'],
                     data: [3, 5],
                     colorByPoint: true,

                     name1: 'Jan UnPlanned Leaves',
                    categories1: ['Admin', 'HR'],
                     data1: [10, 15],
                     colorByPoint: true,

                 },

             }

            ];


            function backChart(name, cat, data)
             {


                    chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(cat);
                               while( chart.series.length > 0 ) {
                                chart.series[0].remove( true );
                            }
                            chart.redraw();

                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                                chart.addSeries({
                                    name: name[i],
                                    data: data[i],
                                    colorByPoint: true,
                                }
                                );

                            }




             }

                   function setChart(name, categories, data, csname, csdata) {
                            console.log(name, categories, data);
                            chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(categories);
                               while( chart.series.length > 0 ) {
                                chart.series[0].remove( true );
                            }
                            chart.redraw();

                            $("#test").html("<button >Back</button>");
                            $("button").click(function( ) 
                             {
                                if(csname=='Planned Leaves' || csname=='Unplanned Leaves')
                                    {
                                        cat=categories3;
                                    }
                               backChart(csname, cat, csdata); 

                            });

                            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                                chart.addSeries({
                                    name: name[i],
                                    data: data[i],
                                    colorByPoint: true,
                                }
                                );

                            }

                        }


                   chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                            chart: {
                                renderTo: 'container',
                                 type: 'column',
                                    options3d: {
                                        enabled: true,
                                        alpha: 25,
                                        beta: 3,
                                        depth: 90,
                                        viewDistance: 25
                                    }
                            },
                            title: {
                                text: 'Employee Leave Management'
                            },
                            subtitle: {
                                text: 'Click the columns to view breakdown by department. Click again to view by Name Wise.'
                            },
                            xAxis: {
                                categories: categories3, 
                                labels: {
                                    align:'center'
                                        }
                            },
                            yAxis: {
                                title: {
                                    text: 'Employee Leave Days'
                                }
                            },
                            plotOptions: {


                                column: {
                                    cursor: 'pointer',
                                    point: {
                                        events: {
                                            click: function () {
                                                var drilldown = this.drilldown;
                                                csname=this.series.name;
                                                csdata=this.series.data;
                                                if (drilldown) { // drill down
                                                    if(csname=='pnun')
                                                    setChart([drilldown.name,drilldown.name1], drilldown.categories, [drilldown.data,drilldown.data1],csname,csdata);  
                                                    else                                     
                                                    setChart([drilldown.name], drilldown.categories, [drilldown.data],csname,csdata);
                                                } 
                                                else { // restore
                                                    setChart(name, categories3, [data1, data2, data3]);
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },


                                    dataLabels: {
                                        enabled: true,
                                        colorByPoint: true,

                                        style: {
                                            fontWeight: 'bold'
                                        },
                                        formatter: function () {
                                            return this.y; //+'%';
                                        }
                                    }

                                }
                            },

                                credits:{
                                    enabled:false

                                },
                                legend:{
                                    enabled:true,

                                },




                            tooltip: {
                                formatter: function () {
                                    var point = this.point,
                                    series = point.series,
                                    s = 'Learner Responsive 16-18' + '<br/>' + this.x + ' ' + series.name + ' is <b>' + this.y + '</b><br/>';
                                    if (point.drilldown) {
                                        s += 'Click to view <b>' + point.category + ' ' + series.name + ' </b>' + ' by department';
                                    } else {

                                        s += 'Click to return to view by academic year.';
                                    }
                                    return s;
                                }
                            },


                            series: [{
                                name: name1,
                                categories:categories1,
                                data: data1,
                                colorByPoint: true
                            },{
                                name: name2,
                                data: data2,
                                categories:categories2,
                                colorByPoint: true
                            },
                            {   name:name3,
                                 data: data3,
                                 visible:false,
                                 categories:categories3,
                                colorByPoint: true,
                                showInLegend:false
                            }
                             ],


                        },
                            function (chart) {
                            console.log(chart);
                        });
                    });
                });
```

Here is my fiddle [**http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedmusthafac/84AK5/1/**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedmusthafac/84AK5/1/)

Comment: At the beginning I advice you to fix your errors (run a console developer tools).

Comment: @sebastian i am not getting u what is the error in that, only thing is i didnt define 'cat', because i do no what to do next

Comment: Excalty, so for the future, please attach example which has no errors. Anyway, your back button should back one level up or for the first "screen". ?